# How to use ifelse in r with multiple conditions to change another variable to NA

Tags: r, if-statement

I have station data with years and rainfall amounts. I am trying to convert specific stations of certain years to missing values (NA) for rainfall. I want everything that is not that specific station/year to keep it's rainfall amount.

I've been using `ifelse` to specify multiple conditions and designate rainfall as NA. But every time I do this my data frame turns into a value that simply is the number of rows that are not NA.

Here's some sample data:

```
STATION<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
YEAR<-c(2000,2001,2002,2000,2001,2002)
RAIN<-c(5,4,3,4,3,5)
df<-cbind(STATION,YEAR,RAIN)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
```

Now, if I want rainfall amounts that are part of station 1 in the year 2001 I am using this ifelse statement:

```
df<-ifelse(df$STATION==1&&df$YEAR==2001,df$RAIN<-"NA",df$RAIN<-df$RAIN)
```

With this code, the df becomes a value of 5.

What I want to get is a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     STATION YEAR   RAIN
[1,] "1"     "2000" "5" 
[2,] "1"     "2001" "NA"
[3,] "1"     "2002" "3" 
[4,] "2"     "2000" "4" 
[5,] "2"     "2001" "3" 
[6,] "2"     "2002" "5"
```

Anyone know where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assignment should be outside the `ifelse`

```
df$RAIN <- ifelse(df$STATION==1 & df$YEAR==2001, NA, df$RAIN)
```

Also, instead of repeating thee 'df$', it would be much easier if we wrap inside `with`

```
df$RAIN <- with(df, ifelse(STATION == 1 & YEAR == 2001, NA, RAIN))
df
#  STATION YEAR RAIN
#1       1 2000    5
#2       1 2001   NA
#3       1 2002    3
#4       2 2000    4
#5       2 2001    3
#6       2 2002    5
```

NOTE: In addition to the assignment, the `&&` should be `&` as the former returns only a single TRUE/FALSE as output.  Also, `data.frame(cbind` would mess up the types of columns as `cbind` returns a `matrix` first and `matrix` can have only a single class.

`NA` should not be quoted.

---

Regarding why only `5` is returned, as mentioned above the `&&` returns a single TRUE/FALSE

```
df$STATION==1&&df$YEAR==2001
#[1] FALSE
```

In the `ifelse`, now the `no` part becomes active, and the first value for 'RAIN' is 5

```
ifelse(df$STATION==1&&df$YEAR==2001, NA,df$RAIN) # modified syntax related issues
#[1] 5
```

This gets assigned to the whole column

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(STATION,YEAR,RAIN)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `dplyr` to achieve the same:

```
library(dplyr)

STATION<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
YEAR<-c(2000,2001,2002,2000,2001,2002)
RAIN<-c(5,4,3,4,3,5)
df<-cbind(STATION,YEAR,RAIN)
df<-as.data.frame(df)

df <- df %>% mutate(RAIN = if_else(STATION == 1 & YEAR == 2001, NA, RAIN))
```

I find its syntax to be more intuitive. In addition, `if_else`, unlike `ifelse`, preserves types and is somewhat faster.